# Getting the BLUE component value of a color structure

Tags: c#, .net

How can i get the BLUE component value of a color?
I would love to see a custom function implementation, not `Color.B`

Comment: Why? What's the problem with `Color.B`? How do you expect it to be gotten out in any other way, seeing as `Color` is not built to expose anything else?

Comment: What do you need a "custom function" for? Do you have a color in some other format than a `Color` instance? If so, specify what that format is instead.

Comment: Define "color". Is that an object to you? A struct? A hex value? How many bits? Are they all crammed into one integer or are they seperated? What's the endianness? Is it RGB? BGR? Some other color space? Etc.

Comment: I am just curious! What does the "Color.B function" contain? How do they do it?.

Comment: Whip out your favourite decompiler and look for yourself.

Comment: @Oded If i could do that, i wouldn't ask here

Comment: Reflector is free. Many other decompilers are free. I don't see how you _can't_ do that.

Comment: @Chris It puzzled me as well. But apparently everyone else here knows they are talking about [`System.Drawing.Color.B`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.b.aspx) in the `System.Drawing.dll` of the framework BCL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) to get the source code for .NET framework namespaces.

Which has this implementation in net\fx\src\CommonUI\System\Drawing\Color.cs for the Color.B property:

```
   public byte B {
       get {
           return(byte)((Value >> ARGBBlueShift) & 0xFF);
       }
   }
```

Where ARGBBlueShift is:

```
    private const int ARGBBlueShift   = 0;
```

A value that *could* conceivably be different on another operating system that stores the colors in a different order.

Comment: Unable to download source from [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx). Clicking on download link downloads some aspx files. I see .NET 2.0 ROTOR sscli [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917).

Answer (score 2):

`Color.B` contains the following:

```
public byte B
{
  [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")] get
  {
    return (byte) ((ulong) this.Value & (ulong) byte.MaxValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: What decompiler generate that one?